# PowerShell modules do not load load within GitHub Docker container Actions

Tags: powershell, github-actions

Running PowerShell cmdlets from modules fails within a GitHub Action with the following error:

```
The term 'Get-AzResourceGroup' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell

RUN pwsh -c "Install-Module AZ";
```

GitHub Workflow

```
name: Run PowerShell in GH Action

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ] 

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: acrURL/imageName
      credentials:
        username: ${{secrets.acrUserName}}
        password: ${{secrets.acrPassword}}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Run 
        shell: pwsh
        run: Get-AzResourceGroup -Name myRG
```

Answer (score 1):

GitHub actions change the user path to `/github/home/.local/share/powershell/Modules` instead of `/root/`.

PowerShell is failing to load the modules because they are located under a different user account. Changing your Dockerfile to install the module to `-Scope AllUsers` will resolve the issue.

New Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell

RUN pwsh -c "Install-Module AZ -Scope AllUsers";
```